# Change session in PHP using PHPSESSID and SERVER[HTTP_COOKIE]

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP session with the following HTTP_COOKIE when I `print_r` **$_SERVER**:

```
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=2oo41phv0l92hbu4gloiraptk7
```

This as the following `$_SESSION["id"]` = 1

When receiving another http request I issued the following lines:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"] = 'PHPSESSID=2oo41phv0l92hbu4gloiraptk7';
echo $_SESSION["id"];
```

And the `echo` said "undefined index in php 'id' ". I'm I doing something bad here? How can I pass the session through php?

Comment: you have to start your `session_start();` in every file your using it!

Comment: @Rizier123 didn't work ;/

Comment: Please specify your question more because i don't really see what your goal is and where the problem is! (Also add your code properly)

Comment: @Rizier123 it's a follow up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972836/bind-php-session-to-http-client

Comment: Do i understand that right: You have 2 php scripts in the first one you get a result for `HTTP_COOKIE` and in the second script you get another result for `HTTP_COOKIE` and also you cannot access your session? (Also: you have 2 scripts right? What is the goal of your code?)

Comment: I have only one script. My goal is to bind my nodejs http request to another php session...